Right clicking caused windows to corrupt
This has happened 3 or 4 times now
This time I right clicked on my desktop and everything got a white faded out look. Task manager showed Exploere.exe was not responding and rebooting take me to the log in screen but logging in brings me to a black screen and the only response I get is the Ctrl+Alt+Del menu but task manager won't open.
This has happened at least twice before but the first time I was right clicking on a file located on my network drive (SMB) and so I thought maybe it was the network drive causing the issue. Then the 2nd time it happned it was on my 6TB HDD in my desktop... so then I thought that maybe it was just an issue with the hard drives on my network and my desktop being old and throwing some kind of error that somehow made windows break. But, then this happened and the desktop is on my NVMe SSD which has no read write errors in it's "S.M.A.R.T." report so I don't even know... I am not bumpy brained enough to know what would cause this kind of issue. I can't figure out how to check the system logs from a live linux USB drive I have but I figured that should be where I start looking. Just can't find any information on how to read them. I also have backups of my C drive from some of the previous times this happened as well and would like to know how to open these logs and see if there's anything useful in them to help figure out what is going wrong.
Here is my CPU-Z Validator results showing my hardware specifications in case you wanted to know what hardware I am on.
https://valid.x86.fr/zgin74
Here is the crash report from Event Viewer
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Hang
Date:          2024-06-01 6:23:33 PM
Event ID:      1002
Task Category: (101)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      MATTHEW-DESKTOP
Description:
The program explorer.exe version 10.0.19041.4355 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the problem is available, check the problem history in the Security and Maintenance control panel.
 Process ID: 5e30
 Start Time: 01dab478d21e8ca4
 Termination Time: 60000
 Application Path: C:\Windows\explorer.exe
 Report Id: 0a0d2798-dc00-48b9-9dfc-7bd0fa9fde0c
 Faulting package full name: 
 Faulting package-relative application ID: 
 Hang type: Unknown

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Hang" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1002</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>101</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-06-02T00:23:33.2197350Z" />
    <EventRecordID>10155</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>MATTHEW-DESKTOP</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>explorer.exe</Data>
    <Data>10.0.19041.4355</Data>
    <Data>5e30</Data>
    <Data>01dab478d21e8ca4</Data>
    <Data>60000</Data>
    <Data>C:\Windows\explorer.exe</Data>
    <Data>0a0d2798-dc00-48b9-9dfc-7bd0fa9fde0c</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>Unknown</Data>
    <Binary>55006E006B006E006F0077006E0000000000</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>


I am not clicking that link. If it's a screenshot, use the upload image function, instead of linking to an unknown image host.

If you look up the URL it comes back as CPU-Z validator. I included it just in case anyone had questions about my hardware.

You originally didn’t describe the URL. It appears to be a screenshot but I can’t tell because of all the ads.

Does it happen when booting in Safe mode?

@Rhamhound My sincerest apologies, I was not thinking much about that and I guess I just assumed since the valid.x86.fr is a well know URL among PC enthusiasts, I didn't stop to think weather or not it would also be known here. Thank you for your assistance in bringing it to my attention, I will do my best to remember to describe what URLs I share in the future. However I would ALWAYS recommend checking any URL posted online especially on message boards since I have read that scammers have been using Unicode characters in URLs to spoof legitimate URLs. Thanks again!
